# R - loess curve not fitted correctly through points

Tags: r, regression, curve, loess

I am trying to filter out points that are too close or below a loess curve:

The result looks like this:[image: Scatterplot with loess curve]

Obviously not the desired outcome.

If however I use the scatter.smooth function I get a correct looking curve:
[image: Scatterplot with scatter.smooth curve]

How can I correctly fit the loess curve through my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly, we should inspect what the `predict` function returns:

```
head(predict(afit))
[1] 0.8548271 0.8797704 0.8584954 0.8031563 0.9012096 0.8955874
```

It's a vector, so when we pass it to `lines`, `R` says, "okay, you didn't specify an x value, so I'll just use the index for the x values" (try `plot(2:10)` to see what I mean).

So, what we need to do is specify a 2 column matrix to pass to `lines`, instead:

`cbind(sort(means), predict(afit, newdata = sort(means)))`

should do the trick. Your function can be written as:

```
FilterByVariance<-function(dat, threshold = 0.90, span = 0.75){
means <- apply(dat,1,mean) 
sds <- apply(dat,1,sd) 
cv <- sqrt(sds/means)

afit<-loess(cv~means, span = span)
resids<-afit$residuals
# good<-which(resids >= quantile(resids, probs = threshold)) 
# points above the curve will have a residual > 0
good <- which(resids > 0)
#plots

plot(cv~means)
lines(cbind(sort(means), predict(afit, newdata = sort(means))), 
      col="blue",lwd=3)
points(means[good],cv[good],col="red",pch=19)

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That definetly solves the problem of the wrongly drawn curve. However the red points are still scattered along the wrong loess curve. Can I fit them on loess curve that is drawn?

Comment: What do you mean they're scattered along the wrong curve? Do you wish to see points which are both above __and__ below the loess?

Comment: The selected dots are still "randomly" scattered around the curve.
http://imgur.com/a/fmKXm
I would like to select only those datapoints that are above the curve.

Comment: Points above the curve will have a residual value > 0. I've updated the function.

Comment: Using the quantile is just a more strict selection, i believe.
At least the result doesn´t look right:
http://imgur.com/a/YDlrD

Comment: Is there a way you could post some of your data. I am having trouble reproducing your result? You might also want to restart your R session and try running it again.

Comment: Sure, here is a link to the Matrix I use:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2I91PZt12z8d21iWkxjR2ZIdVk
I have updated the code in my original question, so you have the complete function I use. I call the function like this:
`gene_counts_filtered <- FilterByVariance(log(gene_counts+1),10)`

Comment: So I found out that its basically a visual bug. If I choose a subset of the matrix, it displays correctly. Thanks for your time!